# How to combine Option values in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, scalaz

I want to be able to apply an operation `f: (T,T) => T` to `Option[T]` values in Scala. I want the result to be `None` if any of the two values is `None`.

More specifically, I want to know if there is a shorter way to do the following:

```
def opt_apply[T](f: (T,T) => T, x: Option[T], y: Option[T]): Option[T] = {
  (x,y) match {
    case (Some(u),Some(v)) => Some(f(u,v))
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

I have tryied `(x zip y) map {case (u,v) => f(u,v)}` but the result is an `Iterator[T]` not an `Option[T]`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
scala> val (x, y) = (Some(4), Some(9))
x: Some[Int] = Some(4)
y: Some[Int] = Some(9)

scala> def f(x: Int, y: Int) = Math.max(x, y)
f: (x: Int,y: Int)Int

scala> for { x0 <- x; y0 <- y } yield f(x0, y0)
res26: Option[Int] = Some(9)

scala> val x = None
x: None.type = None

scala> for { x0 <- x; y0 <- y } yield f(x0, y0)
res27: Option[Int] = None
```

Answer (score 20):

**@RahulG**'s answer exploits the fact that `Option` is a monad (even though there is no type to represent this in the Scala library). The compiler expands the `for` comprehension to the following:

```
def a: Option[Int]
def b: Option[Int]
val calc: Option[Int] = a flatMap {aa => b map {bb => aa + bb}}
```

You can also treat it as an applicative functor, with some help from Scalaz:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def a: Option[Int]
def b: Option[Int]
val calc: Option[Int] = (a ⊛ b) {_ + _}
```

A key difference is that in the monadic calculation, a failure (that is, `None`) of calculation `a` short circuits the evaluation. In the applicative style, both `a` and `b` are evaluated, and if both are `Some`s, the pure function is called. You can also see that in the monadic calculation, the value `aa` could have been used in the calculation `b`; in the applicative version, `b` cannot depend on the result of `a`.

Comment: Is the ASCII equivalent `<|*|>` for this method?

Comment: `<*>` allows you to provide the 'pure' function, in this case `(a, b)=> a + b`. `<|*|>` is a convenience for using `Tuple2.apply` as the pure function. `⊛` is actually a bit more general than arity-2, you could write `(a ⊛ b a ⊛ b) {_ + _ + _ + _}`. It's a little experimental, and as such, doesn't have a ASCII alias yet.

Comment: Typo, I meant: `(a ⊛ b ⊛ a ⊛ b) {_ + _ + _ + _}`

Comment: From the 7th version of Scalaz ASCII alias to `⊛` operator is `|@|`:
`val calc: Option[Int] = (a |@| b) {_ + _}`

Answer (score 3):

I have a slightly older version of **scalaz** than *retronym* but the following works for me as an example and is generalizable for the case where you have 3 types `T, U, V` and not just one:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._

  val opt1 = some(4.0) //Option[Double]
  val opt2 = some(3)   //Option[Int]

  val f: (Double, Int) => String = (d, i) => "[%d and %.2f]".format(i, d)

  val res = (opt1 <|*|> opt2).map(f.tupled)
  println(res) //Some([3 and 4.00])
}
```

I can then add:

```
val opt3 = none[Int]
val res2 = (opt1 <|*|> opt3).map(f.tupled)
println(res2) //None
```

Comment: Replace `<|*|>` with `<*>` to avoid creation of the temporary tuple, and use `f` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, [`Option#zip`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html#zip[A1%3E:A,B](that:Option[B]):Option[(A1,B)]) can be applied to another `Option` to return an `Option` (in earlier versions, it would have returned an `Iterable`); thus:

```
def optApply[T](f: (T,T) => T, a: Option[T], b: Option[T]): Option[T] =
  a.zip(b).map(f.tupled)
```

where the behavior of `zip` is:

```
Some(2).zip(Some(3)) // Some((2, 3))
Some(2).zip(None)    // None
None.zip(Some(3))    // None
None.zip(None)       // None
```

and which can be applied as such:

```
optApply[Int]((a, b) => a max b, Some(2), Some(5)) // Some(5)
optApply[Int]((a, b) => a max b, Some(2), None)    // None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for comprehensions:

```
def opt_apply[T](f: (T,T) => T, x: Option[T], y: Option[T]): Option[T] = 
     for (xp <- x; yp <- y) yield (f(xp,yp))
```

Which is sugar for:

```
x flatMap {xp => y map {yp => f(xp, yp)}}
```

This is also possible due to Option being a Monad

Comment: That's weird. I didn't see @RahulG's answer when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def optApply[A,B,C](f: (A, B) => C, a: Option[A], b: Option[B]): Option[C] =
  a.zip(b).headOption.map { tup => f.tupled(tup) }
```

`a.zip(b)` does result in an Iterable[(A, B)] (with, because it's from Options, at most one element).  `headOption` then returns the first element as an Option.