# Summing a List of Options with Applicative Functors

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have a List[Option[Int]] and want to sum over it using applicative functors.
From [1] I understand that it should be something like the following

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

List(1,2,3).map(some(_)).foldLeft(some(0))({
    case (acc,value) => (acc <|*|> value){_+_}
})
```

however I am simply not able to figure out the correct way to write this. 
I would be glad if somebody could help me with this.

Thank you very much

[1] [How to combine Option values in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712390/how-to-combine-option-values-in-scala)

**Edit**

Thanks for all the great answers.

If there is any None in the list, I want it to return None.
I am trying to replace Null/Exception with Option/Either and see if I can produce some usable code.

Some function will fill my list and I want to process it further as easy as possible without checking if one of the elements was None. It should work similar as Exceptions, where I don't have to check for it in my function, but let the caller take care of it.

Comment: Hi Manuel! Yes the very important part is always how to handle None: Ignore or Fail fast see here for a related example: https://gist.github.com/970717

Comment: Hi Andreas. Code snippets like yours is what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have `Option[T]` and if there's a `Monoid` for `T`, then there's a `Monoid[Option[T]]`:

```
implicit def optionTIsMonoid[T : Monoid]: Monoid[Option[T]] = new Monoid[Option[T]] {
  val monoid = implicitly[Monoid[T]]
  val zero = None
  def append(o1: Option[T], o2: =>Option[T]) = (o1, o2) match {
    case (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(monoid.append(a, b))
    case (Some(a), _)       => o1
    case (_, Some(b))       => o2
    case _                  => zero
  }
}
```

Once you are equipped with this, you can just use `sum` (better than `foldMap(identity)`, as suggested by @missingfaktor):

```
 List(Some(1), None, Some(2), Some(3), None).asMA.sum === Some(6)
```

**UPDATE**

We can actually use applicatives to simplify the code above:

```
implicit def optionTIsMonoid[T : Monoid]: Monoid[Option[T]] = new Monoid[Option[T]] {
   val monoid = implicitly[Monoid[T]]
   val zero = None
   def append(o1: Option[T], o2: =>Option[T]) = (o1 |@| o2)(monoid.append(_, _))
}
```

which makes me think that we can maybe even generalize further to:

```
implicit def applicativeOfMonoidIsMonoid[F[_] : Applicative, T : Monoid]: Monoid[F[T]] = 
  new Monoid[F[T]] {
    val applic = implicitly[Applicative[F]]
    val monoid = implicitly[Monoid[T]]

    val zero = applic.point(monoid.zero)
    def append(o1: F[T], o2: =>F[T]) = (o1 |@| o2)(monoid.append(_, _))
  }
```

Like that you would even be able to sum Lists of Lists, Lists of Trees,...

**UPDATE2**

The question clarification makes me realize that the **UPDATE** above is incorrect!

First of all `optionTIsMonoid`, as refactored, is not equivalent to the first definition, since the first definition will skip `None` values while the second one will return `None` as soon as there's a `None` in the input list. But in that case, this is not a `Monoid`! Indeed, a `Monoid[T]` must respect the Monoid laws, and `zero` must be an [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) element.

We should have:

```
zero    |+| Some(a) = Some(a)
Some(a) |+| zero    = Some(a)
```

But when I proposed the definition for the `Monoid[Option[T]]` using the `Applicative` for `Option`, this was not the case:

```
None    |+| Some(a) = None
None    |+| None    = None
=> zero |+| a      != a

Some(a) |+| None    = zero
None    |+| None    = zero
=> a    |+| zero   != a
```

The fix is not hard, we need to change the definition of `zero`:

```
// the definition is renamed for clarity
implicit def optionTIsFailFastMonoid[T : Monoid]: Monoid[Option[T]] = 
  new Monoid[Option[T]] {
    monoid = implicitly[Monoid[T]]
    val zero = Some(monoid.zero)
    append(o1: Option[T], o2: =>Option[T]) = (o1 |@| o2)(monoid.append(_, _))
  }
```

In this case we will have (with `T` as `Int`):

```
Some(0) |+| Some(i) = Some(i)
Some(0) |+| None    = None
=> zero |+| a       = a

Some(i) |+| Some(0) = Some(i)
None    |+| Some(0) = None
=> a    |+| zero    = zero
```

Which proves that the identity law is verified (we should also verify that the [associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative) law is respected,...).

Now we have 2 `Monoid[Option[T]]` which we can use at will, depending on the behavior we want when summing the list: skipping `None`s or "failing fast".

Comment: Just after posting this, I realize that I'm not really answering the question, since I'm not using any Applicative. Just consider this as one of the numerous alternatives,...

Comment: I don't understand how that works... why is there no `+` anywhere?

Comment: `.foldMap(identity)` can be replaced by `.asMA.sum`.

Comment: The `+` is provided by the fact that there is a `Monoid` for `T`. If `T` is an `Int` Scalaz provides a `Monoid[Int]` where the `append` operation is defined using `+`. So the advantage of my solution is that it's a bit more generic because it extends to anything having an "addition-like" operation.

Comment: @Eric A minor mistake: **a |+| zero = a** for identity law:)

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you for your detailed answer. I will need some time to fully understand it since I am relatively new to fp. It seems to be a little bit complicated and I at the moment I would prefer to throw an exception

Answer (score 15):

You don't really need Scalaz for this.  You can just flatten the list, which will convert it to `List[Int]`, removing any items that were `None`.  Then you can reduce it:

```
List(Some(1), None, Some(2), Some(3), None).flatten.reduce(_ + _) //returns 6: Int
```

Comment: I had interpreted it as wanting to make the result `None` if any were `None`, but now that you mention, I'm not so sure I was right...

Comment: Very good point, I suppose the OP should specify whether he wants the sum to fail if at least one item is None, or to sum over items that have values, ignoring the Nones.

Answer (score 6):

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).map(some).foldLeft(0 some) {
     |   case (r, c) => (r |@| c)(_ + _)
     | }
res180: Option[Int] = Some(6)
```

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to sequence the whole list first, then fold it like regular:

```
val a: List[Option[Int]] = List(1, 2, 3) map (Some(_))
a.sequence map (_.foldLeft(0)(_+_))
```

Comment: Or, indeed, just a.sequence map {_.sum}

Answer (score 0):

With Scalaz's ApplicativeBuilder would be another option.

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

List(1,2,3).map(_.some).foldl1((acc,v) => (acc |@| v) {_+_}) join
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this somewhere a while ago, can't find the source anymore, but it has been working for me

```
 def sumOpt1(lst: List[Option[Int]]): Option[Int] = {
    lst.foldLeft(Option.empty[Int]) {
      case (prev, elem) =>
        (prev, elem) match {
          case (None, None) => None
          case (None, Some(el)) => Some(el)
          case (Some(p), None) => Some(p)
          case (Some(p), Some(el)) => Some(p + el)
        }
    }
  }
```

or

```
 def sumOpt2(lst: List[Option[Int]]): Option[Int] = {
    lst.foldLeft(Option.empty[Int]) {
      case (prev, elem) =>
        (prev, elem) match {
          case (None, None) => None
          case (p, el) => Some(p.getOrElse(0) + el.getOrElse(0))
        }
    }
  }
```

or

```
def sumOpt3(lst: List[Option[Int]]): Option[Int] = {
    lst.foldLeft(Option.empty[Int]) {
      case (prev, elem) =>
        (prev, elem) match {
          case (None, el) => el
          case (p, None) => p
          case (Some(p), Some(el)) => Some(p + el)
        }
    }
  }
```