# Type mis-match after flattening a Some(Option) in fold function

Tags: scala

I want to get the product of a `List[Option[Int]]`, and flatten it to `Option[Int]`:

```
List(Some(2), Some(3), Some(5)).foldLeft(Some(1)) { (x, y) =>

  // err
  x.map(ix => y.map(iy => ix * iy)).flatten

  //   // workaround
  //   x.map(ix => y.map(iy => ix * iy)).flatten match {
  //    case Some(acc) => Some(acc)
  //     case _ => Some(0)
  //   }

}
```

the err in detail:

```
polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : [B]Option[B]
[error]  required: Some[Int]
[error]       x.map(ix => y.map(iy => ix * iy)).flatten 
[error]
```

`flatten` in `foldLeft` didn't return `Some[Int]`?  What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x.map(ix => y.map(iy => ix * iy)).flatten
```

returns an `Option[Int]`, based on the value of the `x` and `y`, i.e. if either `x` or `y` is `None` the value is `None`, otherwise it is `Some[Int]`.

In your fold statement, your seed value is `Some(1)` whose type is `Some[Int].` Compiler expects the same type from the result of the fold statement. But the result value of the expression of the fold statement is `Option[Int]`. Hence, the error, the required type is `Some[Int]` as of the seed value, but compiler found `Option[Int]` from the fold expression.

Any of the other answer works. The closet to your expression will be simply change your seed value to `Option(1)` from `Some(1)`, so that the type of seed value and type from the fold statement matches, like

```
List(Some(2), Some(3), Some(5)).foldLeft(Option(1)) { (x, y) => ....
```

Comment: Thanks. Btw, what does the `[error]  found  : [B]Option[B]` mean? esp. the [B] before Option[B]?

Comment: @maow - Sorry, but I don't know. Scala compiler goes through lots of hoops to make things work with JVM and also to preserve type-safety. Sometimes the internal implementation of the clever technology that makes things work leaks into the errors/type signatures in the scala library. I usually take scala errors with a pinch of salt, rather than on its face value

Answer (score 1):

If your list is actually a `List[Option[Int]]` then for a working example you need to declare them as such. It would be great if someone could chime in on exactly why since I'm not sure.

```
val xs = List(Option(2), Option(3), Option(5))

xs.reduceRight((x, b) => x.flatMap(y => b.map(z => y * z)))
// res0: Option[Int] = Some(30)
```

Note however if any element in the list of Options is `None` then the evaluation will "short circuit" and return a `None`. If you don't want this then I believe you will need to look at some solutions from `scalaz` such as applicative functors, there's some discussion this here [Summing a List of Options with Applicative Functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147031/summing-a-list-of-options-with-applicative-functors)

Answer (score 0):

This works and is simpler:

```
List(Some(2), Some(3), Some(5)).flatten.foldLeft(1) { (x, y) => x * y}
```

Flattten removes Nones and gives you List[Int].

Comment: This is a better answer. Also, IntelliJ hinted that you can replace the entire foldLeft function with `.product`. So it would be `List(..).flatten.product`

Comment: This is a better solution, but not what I asked. Sorry didn't make it clear, the precondition was operations should be taken on Option[Int].