# Reducing options in scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, reduce, scalaz, option-type

What is the best way to do this:

```
def reduce[A](x: Option[A], y: Option[A])(f: (A, A) => A): Option[A] = 
  (x, y) match {
    case (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(f(a, b))
    case (None, None) => None
    case (_,  None) => x
    case (None, _) => y
  }
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712390/how-to-combine-option-values-in-scala) question but his case is slightly different from mine...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The shortest is probably

```
(x ++ y).reduceLeftOption(f)
```

which works because of an implicit conversion from `Option` to `Iterable` which happens to have a method that does exactly what you need.