# scala condition when all param option are met

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am using play2 framework, so when I retrieving parameters I always get `Option`. But I will only continue to process only if all the Options are matched (Not None).

I don't want to write nested `match` as that looks ugly.

```
if( isDefined("a") && isDefined("b"){
    //dosomething 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match them as a tuple

```
(aOpt, bOpt) match {
  case (Some(aVal), Some(bVal)) => ...
  case _ => ...
}
```

You could use for-comprehension syntax

```
for {
  aVal <- aOpt
  bVal <- bOpt
} ...
```

There are also some monadic combinators (`(aOpt |@| bOpt) {aVal + bVal}`) in the Scalaz library if you want to go that road.

[Here are a similar question + answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712390/how-to-combine-option-values-in-scala).